# How can I specify a radius for Kitkat Dialer business search?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, phone-app

I like the business search in the Kitkat dialer, but it seems to have an odd concept of "nearby".  It will often give me results in different regions of the country, and if it can't find any, it will show me results in nearby countries.

Is there any way to limit the radius of the business search to be only within a certain radius?